# Android Jetpack Compose - R.drawable not found?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I recently started learning Jetpack Compose. Here is problem.
When i try to create image android studio can't find R.drawable folder. It looks like that.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdekv.png)
Why is that?

@Edit:
Thank You! Importing R helped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Be careful that **R** is imported correctly.

```
import [BASE_PACKAGE_NAME].R
```

and check  is painterResource imported correctly?

```
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
```

Comment: Thank you, I could not figure this outl.  Wonder if something changed.

Comment: FWIW - during my journey to resolve this (and I think it is a compiler bug to not assume R is not import-able), I added this dependency to build.gradle that resulted in "duplicate class" compiler error.   Removed this: implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.0"

Answer (score 0):

Imports in Compose are super important. A small piece like dp or sp can also loose context without specific imports like import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp, or import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp